# Assertion trying to delete an empty object

Tags: c++

trying to solve a mem leak I've changed this:

```
void addListener(IListener* listener, const std::string& appender )
{
     std::pair<t_ListenerVectorMap::iterator,bool> p =
    listenerVectorMap.insert(std::string(appender), new t_ListenerVector);
    p.first->second->push_back(listener);

    //add the appender
    addAppender(appender);
}
```

By this:

```
void addListener( IListener* listener,const std::string& appender )
{
    t_ListenerVector* lv = new t_ListenerVector;
    std::pair<t_ListenerVectorMap::iterator,bool> p =
    listenerVectorMap.insert(std::string(appender), lv);

    p.first->second->push_back(listener);
    if (!p.second)
    {
        delete lv;
    }

    addAppender(appender);
}
```

The leak I'm trying to get ride is the new t_ListenerVector (is a boost::ptr_vector). When appender already exists into listenerVectorMap, then insert operation doesn't not modify contents of map, so new t_ListenerVector isn't inserted and becomes a mem leak.

The change is to avoid this leak. If no new insertion as been done, lv is not inserted so I do remove it. But the problem is that delete lv throws an assertion (in vc\include\vector Line:70).
If lv hasn't been changed, why this error?

Some ideas are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: You can't "throw an assertion". You can throw an exception, or fail an assertion. What exactly happens, what's the error? And what's the definitio od `t_ListenerVector`?

Comment: And `delete lv` shouldn't fail anyways since `lv` is a pointer to something from `new`.

Comment: Use smart pointer `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, it will both eliminate leaks and make code exception safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer I am assuming that the type of `t_ListenerVectorMap` is `boost::ptr_map<std::string, boost::ptr_vector<IListener>>`. If it isn't then this answer is probably worthless.

---

You have a misunderstanding about how `boost::ptr_map` works. It is true that your original code contains a memory leak, but your replacement code is even worse. `listenerVectorMap.insert(std::string(appender), lv)` makes `listenerVectorMap` take ownership of `lv`, regardless of whether `lv` is inserted or not. This means that the `delete lv;` line results in a double-deletion.

To fix the memory leak in the first version of your code, all you have to do is this:

```
void addListener(IListener* listener, const std::string& appender )
{
    std::auto_ptr<IListener> ls(listener);
    //The original code leaked here if the std::string constructor threw.
    std::pair<t_ListenerVectorMap::iterator,bool> p =
        listenerVectorMap.insert(appender, new t_ListenerVector());
    p.first->second->push_back(ls);

    //add the appender
    addAppender(appender);
}
```

Comment: Yes! your solution works fine, but mem leak is still present.

Comment: @Killrazor - 1) What it the type of `listenerVectorMap`? 2) Why do you think there is a leak is in this part of the code? 3) Are you using the latest version of boost?

Comment: 1.- The ListenerVectorMap is boost::ptr_map<std::string, boost.:ptr_map> 2.-I'm playing with VLD, a leak detector. Maybe I don't understand the result but it marks this method as a leak. 3- Not the latest, but not a prehistoric one (1.45)

Answer (score 2):

do the check to see if it exists in the map *first*, then call new to create the object. This isn't necessarily the source of the bug, but it's a more efficient practice.

Comment: +1: Definitely good advice. It also makes the code more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

If the assertion is coming from your call to delete I would check to make sure that:

1. lv is properly initialised. Maybe it's got a floating pointer interally which by calling delete calls it's destructor and makes it try to free a random bit of memory?
2. if insert fails that it doesn't clear your memory for you?

Some more specific information on the exact error report would be helpful.